# Aperiodic signals fourier transform short question?

Tags: fourier-analysis

What is the fourier transform of the aperiodic signals with infinite sequence? How about the transform of aperiodic  fourier signals with finite sequence?

Comment: Hello, fsdd. Please see [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question) post about how to ask for help with homework. Also, excellent advice on how to ask a good question in general can be found [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960).

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not really sure what kind of answer you are looking for, I'll try:

I'll assume we are talking about continuous signals. The fourier transform of an aperiodic continuous signal is a way to represent the signal as a weighted integral of complex exponentials. The transform is defined as:

$$\hat{f}(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)e^{-j{\omega}t} dt$$

Where $f(t)$ is the original signal, ${\omega}$ is the angular frequency, ${t}$ is time. This is valid for both finite and infinite sequences. (For finite sequences, the integral can be cropped to the signal's span.)

Basically the transform is a domain change - the original signal is a function in time domain returning the signal's value at a given time, while its fourier transform is a function in frequency domain returning the amount of given angular frequency in the signal.

If this is not what you are looking for, please further define your question.